# Ringtone for each sender in whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp.app

I want to give different sound for each sender in whatsapp ( not group ) 
Example: i have 10 contacts in whatsapp so i want each person when send massage i give it different sound means 10 different sound for 10 different contacts. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. Since WhatsApp messages are (technically) iOS notifications, and WhatsApp (as of now) does not allow this customization within the app itself, you cannot achieve this.